# How to add new icon next to Glyphicon-edit(edit mode) on Dashboard using Angular dashboard framework?

Tags: angularjs, angular, dashboard

I am new to ADF, I am trying to add new icon next to it. I went through files and documentation of ADF could not able to find where exactly to change icon and add new one.
some one please guide me where to change in Angular dashboard framework

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: As of now, I am trying to change default ADF code. ex:<i class=glyphicon x-ng-class="{\'glyphicon-edit\' : !editMode, \'glyphicon-save\' : editMode}"> when i change over here. I do not see any changes on my dashboard.